# How to refactor huge if-statement chain with multiple math expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, if-statement, jsx

I have a snippet of perfectly running code but it's ugly and clunky, I'm looking for a more efficiently compressed if-statement for it

```
//my code

function func_tion() {
  let someval_1 = this.x;
  let someval_2 = this.y;

  let val_A=//dynamic integer
  let val_B=//dynamic integer

  let loc_x =//dynamic integer
  let loc_y =//dynamic integer


  if (val_A - loc_x <= 5 && val_A - loc_x >= -5 || loc_x - val_A <= 5 && loc_x - val_A >= -5) {


    if (val_B - loc_y <= 5 && val_B - loc_y >= -5 || loc_y - val_B <= 5 && loc_y - val_B >= -5) {


      if (val_A > loc_x && val_A - loc_x <= 5) { this.x = this.x - 1 };
      if (loc_x > val_A && loc_x - val_A <= 5) { this.x = this.x + 1 };
      if (loc_y > val_B && loc_y - val_B <= 5) { this.y = this.y + 1 };
      if (val_B > loc_y && val_B - loc_y <= 5) { this.y = this.y - 1 };

      if (val_A === loc_x && val_B === loc_y) { console.log("match") };


    } else { this.y = this.y + 1; this.x = this.x + 1; };
  } else { this.x = this.x + 1; this.y = this.y + 1 };
};
```

Comment: `Math.abs` will help a bit

Comment: You can post in codereview site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you looking for it to be compressed, or easily readable and editable? Those two outcomes might be working in opposite directions.

Comment: Whatever you do , make sure you write unit tests with the `current version` of the `perfectly running code`, so that when you `refactor` you can ensure that it works as it used be before the refactoring. Anything other is a subjective team culture matter.

Comment: @AvinashReddy, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: This would be immediately closed on Code Review, as example/obfuscated code lacking any review context, as well as being completely without any description of the intended behaviour.